# Windows Media Player cannot update

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player

When I try to update WMP, I get the following error message:

```
An unexpected error has occured. Setup was not able to detect any Windows Media updates. Please try again later.
```

I am on Windows 7 64 bit. WMP version is 12.0.7601.17514

What causes this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: WMP 12 is the latest version of WMP for Windows 7. That's the reason this error - there are no available updates for WMP, because you already have the latest version. Even if there's a newer build, there is no reason updating WMP anyway.

Comment: @amiregelz no this error will not occur when you have latest version. Then it will say `you have already latest version of WMP`

Comment: Can you look into the event log and post any errors that have been logged there ?